# Why is Bézout's identity considered an identity?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, terminology, euclidean-algorithm

In most cases, identities seem to take values and give outputs that are irrelevant to the input data.

example:
  $(a + b)^2  =  a^2 + 2ab + b^2$
  $[\cos(x)]^2 + [\sin(x)]^2 = 1$

Yet Bézout's identity only seems to assert the existence of something, not a relation of the above kind.

Am I missing something, maybe a way to look at it?

[I know this isn't like a usual rigorous question, but something worth considering for those who enjoy mathematical literature]

Views even if undecisive would be appreciated.

Comment: The term identity is often used to describe an equality. For example, Euler's identity.

Comment: People are quirky and inconsistent in their language use.  That's really all that can be said.  I personally don't like the term "Bezout's Identity" for the exact reasons you state so I'd tell the world to stop using it.  But apparently the world doesn't seem to revolve around me so ... no one pays attention when I do.

Answer (score 4):

One way to view Bezout as an *identity* is to define functions $a_{x,y},\ b_{x,y}\,$ so that

$$     a_{x,y}\ x + b_{x,y}\ y\, =\, 1\ \  \ {\rm for\ all\ coprime}\,\ x,y\in\Bbb Z$$

Such functions implicitly exist in most extended Euclidean algorithm software. Compare

$$\bmod xy\!:\ \ \bar a_{x,y}\,x + \bar b_{x,y}\,y\,\equiv\, 1\ \ \ {\rm for\ all\ coprime}\,\ x,y\in\Bbb Z\qquad\qquad\ \ $$

by using the functions $\ \ \bar a_{x,y} = x^{-1}\bmod y,\,\ \bar b_{x,y} = y^{-1}\bmod x,\, $  see $ $ [Inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242).

For Bezout we can put: $\ a_{x,y} = x^{-1}\bmod y,\,\ b_{x,y} = (1-a_{x,y}\,x)/y \ $ for example.

The general Bezout identity (for all $\,x,y\neq 0,0)$ reduces to the above by cancelling $\gcd(x,y)$

**Remark** $ $  We introduced the functions $\,a,\,b\,$ in order to eliminate the *existential* quatifiers in $\, \forall\, x,y\ \exists\, a,b\!:\ ax + b y = 1,\,$ which leaves only *universal* quantifiers remaining, i.e. an "identity". The same idea works generally - see [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form).

A well known example is inverses: $\,\forall\, x\ \exists\, y\!:\ xy\, = 1,\,$ where we define the inverse function $\,y_x = x^{-1}\,$ which yields the *identity* $\,\forall x\!:\ x\,x^{-1} = 1\,$ in groups. Notice the close relationship with the modular example above, where the functions actually are (modular) *inverses*.

.

Comment: This needs something extra I think. Namely a specification of the representative for $x^{-1} \mod y$?

For example, take $x = 2, y = 3$. Then $2^{-1} \equiv 2 \mod 3$ and $3^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod 2$. But $2 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 3 = 7$. Maybe I misunderstand your notation? Do you mean that there exists a representative such that the identity holds?

Comment: I see you've made an edit. This makes more sense.

Comment: @RubenduBurck Yes, was editing it while you were replying

Comment: @BillDubuque is this the usual modulo notation, a = b (mod n) implies n divides a-b ? if so, what does x(x inverse mod y) mean, just finished high school, would appreciate the extra time of yours I'm taking

Comment: @John_Nash Yes, but I also use the binary operation mod (= remainder)

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) states:

> This article is about Bézout's theorem in arithmetic.

and also

> In elementary number theory, Bézout's identity (also called Bézout's lemma) is the following theorem:

Already, the result is called an identity, theorem, and lemma. The 
terminology used in mathematics is not always precise and depends
on context. Usually, if there is an equation, then in some cases, 
it can be called an identity, especially if it is true for all
values of the variables. Given any integers $\,a\,$
and $\,b\,$, then the Bezout equation
$\, ax+by=d \,$ is true if $\,d\,$ is the GCD of $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$
for some integers $\,x\,$ and $\,y\,$ which are not specified, but only
known to exist and not unique. They can be computed using the extended
Euclidean algorithm which is an efficient, effective algorithm. Perhaps
a better name would be Bezout's equation, but I have never seen that in
print.

What makes it somewhat peculiar is that, unlike the quadratic equation
which has a solution using the quadratic formula, there is **no** similar
formula for the solution of Bezout's equation. It would be a nice result
if there was a formula, but even though it is a linear equation, there are
**two** unknowns. At best, if we know the value of $\,x,\,$ then the formula
$\,y = (d-ax)/b\,$ gives the value of $\,y,\,$ and similarly if we
know the value of $\,y,\,$ then there is the formula
 $\, x = (d-by)/a\,$ for the value of $\,x.$

Comment: I agree that an explicit formula is missing. That is what makes it useful to Cryptography from what I've read.

Comment: @John There are in fact formulas for the Bezout coefficients (in terms of modular inverses) - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Well, how is the modular inverse computed? My understanding is that Euclidean Algorithm is used as in Bezout's identity, and so it is a circular formula.

Comment: @Somos No,there are plenty of other ways to compute inverses without (explicitly) compting the Bezout identity, e.g. by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242), or little Fermat and repeated squaring, etc. But we can easily compute one from the other, so they are equivalent in that sense.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for that comment! I just did not immediately think about the **other ways** to compute inverses because I depend on CAS to do the calculations, although I knew about some of them.